R- How to group a series of values by the hundredth digit after the decimal separator
I have a data frame with two columns. First column is "Ratio", and the second column has numbers that represent the value measured at that ratio.
For example:
   Ratio Intensity
1  0.000  1387.785
2  0.001  1325.254
3  0.003  1307.926
4  0.004  1286.817
5  0.006  1276.197
6  0.007  1251.381
7  0.008  1249.394
8  0.010  1251.923
9  0.011  1263.183
10 0.013  1265.272
11 0.014  1303.354
12 0.015  1336.920
13 0.017  1362.173
14 0.018  1395.946
...

I want to sort the data and sum the intensity:
   Ratio Intensity
1  0.00  1297.822
2  0.01  1311.253
3  0.02  1307.926
4  0.03  1286.817
5  0.04  1276.197
6  0.05  1251.381
7  0.06  1249.394
8  0.07  1251.923
9  0.08  1263.183
10 0.09  1265.272
11 0.10  1303.354
12 0.11  1336.920
13 0.12  1362.173
14 0.13  1395.946

How can I write a script in R to sum and export into a new csv file?
Thank you!

Needs more clarity

floor and aggregate maybe
> aggregate(Intensity ~ cbind(Ratio=I(floor(Ratio*100)/100)), d, mean)
  Ratio Intensity
1  0.00  1297.822
2  0.01  1311.253


Data:
> dput(d)
structure(list(Ratio = c(0, 0.001, 0.003, 0.004, 0.006, 0.007, 
0.008, 0.01, 0.011, 0.013, 0.014, 0.015, 0.017, 0.018), Intensity = c(1387.785, 
1325.254, 1307.926, 1286.817, 1276.197, 1251.381, 1249.394, 1251.923, 
1263.183, 1265.272, 1303.354, 1336.92, 1362.173, 1395.946)), class = "data.frame", row.names = c("1", 
"2", "3", "4", "5", "6", "7", "8", "9", "10", "11", "12", "13", 
"14"))


Looks like you want the mean, not the sum.
library(dplyr)
read.table(text = "   Ratio Intensity
1  0.000  1387.785
2  0.001  1325.254
3  0.003  1307.926
4  0.004  1286.817
5  0.006  1276.197
6  0.007  1251.381
7  0.008  1249.394
8  0.010  1251.923
9  0.011  1263.183
10 0.013  1265.272
11 0.014  1303.354
12 0.015  1336.920
13 0.017  1362.173
14 0.018  1395.946") |>
  as.data.frame() |>

  # Group by hundredth
  mutate(group = floor(Ratio*100)/100) |>

  # mean per group
  summarize(mean = mean(Intensity), .by = group)

Then see functions like write.csv() to save that to a CSV.
Result
  group     mean
1  0.00 1297.822
2  0.01 1311.253

